# Difference between 1 Shared vCPU and 1 vCPU

Tags: google-cloud-platform

In GCP, what is the difference between an f1-micro instance (1 *shared* vCPU) vs. a n1-standard-1 (1 vCPU)? Specifically, what is the difference between a shared vCPU and a vCPU?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Shared-core machine types
>
> Shared-core machine types provide one virtual CPU that is allowed to
>   run for a portion of the time on a single hardware hyper-thread on the
>   host CPU running your instance. Shared-core instances can be more
>   cost-effective for running small, non-resource intensive applications
>   than standard, high- memory or high-CPU machine types.

Source: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types#sharedcore

For your information, with one shared vCPU, Google doesn't guarantee it.

Comment: Adding a comment because this is a high traffic answer for this question and I recently discovered interesting information about the shared core machines. For `e2-small` and `e2-medium` machine types, when used in Dataflow, they are charged as if they were using 2 vCPU constantly. I learned about this after noticing that a streaming Dataflow job with one `e2-small` worker was being charged USD$4.19/day for vCPU time.